# Any tool for triggering Eclipse buttons automatically and orderly?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

There are several Java sub-project that managed by Maven in my working set.

My workflow is that after modify code ,I click buttons to `install`(Maven command) projects one by one , and then click buttons to run projects one by one. Doing all of them by hand and any one of them should be triggered before previous one haven done.

[I click these buttons to install and run projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0JYa.jpg)

Is there any Eclipse tool or any thing else can do that automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Eclipse Advanced Scripting Environment](https://www.eclipse.org/ease/), which was designed to script the Eclipse IDE itself (in JavaScript, Python, etc.).